# Unity In-App Purchasing requires Unity Gaming Services warning

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, in-app-purchase

> Unity IAP: Unity In-App Purchasing requires Unity Gaming Services to have been initialized before use.

This log warning shows when I compile and I've followed the instructions to go to the IAP catalog window and check on 'initialize Unity Gaming Services' so therefore it should be initializing Unity Gaming Services right? Apparently not and I'm not sure why. I've tried the manual way of doing it too suggested in Unity docs.  Are there any other ways to initialize Unity Gaming Services that I'm missing because this method doesn't work?

https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.purchasing@4.2/manual/UnityIAPInitializeUnityGamingServices.html

Comment: Don't worry about it. That's bit alright [Pudge - Dota2]

Comment: Are you saying that it doesn't matter if the warning is there? Why?